# About Linear algebra question.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field, $n$ a positive integer, and $V$ be the space of $n \times n$ matrices over $F$. If $A$ is a fixed $n \times n$ matrix over F,  $ T_A(B) = AB - BA$. Consider the family of linear operators $T_A$ obtained by letting $A$ vary over all diagonal matrices.

Prove that the operators in that family are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts and have tried things that you can share so better guidance can be provided? Regards

Comment: Operators are simultaneously diagonalizable if and only if they commute and are diagonalizable individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints for you to understand and prove:

1) Suppose $\,A,B\,$ are simultaneously diagonalizable (=s.d.) , then there exists invertible $\,P\,$ s.t.:

$$D_1=P^{-1}AP\;,\;\;D_2=P^{-1}BP\;\text{are diagonal}\implies A=PD_1P^{-1}\;,\;B=PD_2P^{-1}\;,\;$$

$$AB=PD_1P^{-1}PD_2P^{-1}=PD_1D_2P^{-1}=PD_2D_1P^{-1}=PD_2P^{-1}PD_1P^{-1}=BA$$

2) Suppose $\,A,B\,$ commute **and** both have minimal polynomials without multiple roots (iff the min. pol. is a product of *different* linear factors iff the matrix/operator is diagonalizable). Let $\,\lambda\,$ be an eigenvalue of $\,A\,$ and let $\,V_{A,\lambda}\,$ be the corresponding eigenspace, so:

$$v\in V_{A,\lambda}\implies A\color{red}{Bv}=BAv=B(\lambda v)=\lambda\color{red}{Bv}\implies Bv\in V_{A,\lambda}\implies$$

$\,V_{A,\lambda}\,$ is $\,B$- invariant, so if $\,\beta\,$ is a basis of the linear space formed by eigenvectors of $\,A\,$, the matrix representation of $\,B\,$ wrt $\,\beta\,$ is a block one, with one block for each different eigenvalue of $\,A\,$ , but

(i) A block matrix is diagonalizable iff each block is

(ii) There exists a new basis of $\,V_{A,\lambda}\,$ under which B is diagonal... **but also** $\,A\,$ is (why?) .

Complete the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Prove that $T_{A_1}$ and $T_{A_2}$ commute  for all  diagonal  $A_1,A_2$.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may prove that for every diagonal matrix $A$, the matrix representation of $T_A$ w.r.t. the standard basis of $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ *is* already diagonal. (You may need [Kronecker product and the vec operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations).) So, there is no need to diagonalise it in the first place.

Comment: I think it may be you misread the question: it must be shown that the set $\,\{T_A\;;\;A\;\text{is diagonal}\}\,$ is **simultaneously** diagonalizable, which is way stronger than merely to show that each $\,T_A\,$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: @DonAntonio No, I didn't misread the question. What I am saying is that, without doing anything, the matrix representations ($I\otimes A-A^T\otimes I$) of ***all*** the $T_A$s are already ***diagonal*** and that's why they are simultaneously *diagonalisable*.

Comment: I don't see why if all the $\,T_A$'s are diagonalizable then they are *simultaneously* diagonalizable. This is false, in general, so why in this case it is true *only from the fact you mention*?

Comment: @DonAntonio What I said is "all $T_A$s are *diagonal* $\Rightarrow$ they are simultaneously diagonalisable", **not** "all $T_A$s are *diagonalisable* $\Rightarrow$ they are simultaneously diagonalisable".

Comment: @DonAntonio As an analogue, suppose you are asked to show that $A=I,B=2I$ and $C=3I$ are simultaneously diagonalisable. One way to show this, of course, is to prove that $A,B,C$ commute with each other and each of them is diagonalisable. However, this is really unnecessary, because $A,B,C$ are already diagonal matrices!

Comment: I know, @user1551, and I asked you, and ask you again, why is this true *in this case*?

Comment: Ah! So **now** you used in your final comment, @user1551, finally!, the argument of commutativity. That's all I was talking about...

Comment: @DonAntonio The Kronecker product of two diagonal matrices is diagonal. Since $A$ is diagonal, the matrix of $T_A$, i.e. $I\otimes A-A^T\otimes I$, is diagonal.

Comment: This is already confusing me a little too much, @user1551: all my point in the comments above is to ask how your answer shows there is *simultaneous* diagonalization. All you mention about Kroenecker product, $\,T_A\,$ being diagonalizable for diagonal $\,A\,$ , etc. is clear to me. The problem, for me at least, is what about simultaneously?!

Comment: @DonAntonio Hmm, what do you mean? If you have a family $\mathcal{S}$ of **diagonal** (I mean "diagonal", not just "diagonalisable") matrices, they are of course simultaneously diagonalisable. In fact, $IAI^{-1}$ is diagonal for every $A\in \mathcal{S}$.